# Show Vandermonde matrix is invertible without using determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ are different elements from the field $F$ (if $i\neq j$, then $a_i\neq a_j$). Show that this matrix is invertible:
$$V=\begin{bmatrix}
1 && 1&&\dots&&1\\
a_1&&a_2&&\dots&&a_n\\
a_1^2&&a_2^2&&\dots&&a_n^2\\
\vdots&&\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
a_1^{n-1}&&a_2^{n-1}&&\dots&&a_n^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Matrix $V$ is a Vandermonde matrix. I don't want to use determinant anywhere. Also I don't know about being linearly independent and I don't want to use it here. These are the thing I know:

- Elementary Row Operations and Elementary Row Matrices
- Row-Reduced Echelon Forms
- Row Equivalence
- If $Ax=0$ has only one answer, then $A$ is invertible

And things like this as I'm reading *K. Hoffman* and *R. Kunze* book about linear algebra. I want to show $V$ is invertible only using things I said above. If you want to use something that you doubt if I know or not, I would be thankful if you ask in the comments. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: they give the proof in the section on Lagrange Interpolation. Given two bases for a vector space, the change of basis matrix (in either direction) is invertible; one direction is your Vandermonde matrix. The proof that it is a change of basis matrix is the Lagrange interpolation formula,

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4792501/14578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof by induction on $n$: For $n=1$ this is trivial (why?). Now write
$$
V_n = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_n\\
a_1^2 & a_2^2 & \cdots & a_n^2\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
a_1^{n-1} & a_2^{n-1} & \cdots & a_n^{n-1}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and assume that $V_n$ is invertible and consider the matrix $V_{n+1}$. Now we apply a sequence of elementary row operations: Starting from row $n+1$ and finishing with row $2$, substract from row $j$ row $j-1$ multiplied by $a_{n+1}$. In terms of elementary matrices this amounts to the same as multiplying $V_{n+1}$ to the left by a sequence of $n$ elementary matrices and hence by an invertible matrix $A_1$. Thus We obtain
$$
A_1V_{n+1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1\\
a_1-a_{n+1} & a_2-a_{n+1} & \cdots & a_n-a_{n+1} & 0\\
a_1(a_1-a_{n+1}) & a_2(a_2-a_{n+1}) & \cdots & a_n(a_n-a_{n+1}) & 0\\
a_1^2(a_1-a_{n+1}) & a_2^2(a_2-a_{n+1}) & \cdots & a_n^2(a_n-a_{n+1}) & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots\\
a_1^{n-1}(a_1-a_{n+1}) & a_2^{n-1}(a_2-a_{n+1}) & \cdots & a_n^{n-1}(a_n-a_{n+1}) & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now consider the traspose matrix
$$
V_{n+1}^TA_1^T = (A_1V_{n+1})^T = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a_1-a_{n+1} & a_1(a_1-a_{n+1}) & a_1^2(a_1-a_{n+1}) & \cdots & a_1^{n-1}(a_1-a_{n+1})\\
1 & a_2-a_{n+1} & a_2(a_2-a_{n+1}) & a_2^2(a_2-a_{n+1}) & \cdots & a_2^{n-1}(a_2-a_{n+1})\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
1 & a_n-a_{n+1} & a_n(a_n-a_{n+1}) & a_n^2(a_n-a_{n+1}) & \cdots & a_n^{n-1}(a_1-a_{n+1})\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Since $a_j-a_{n+1}\neq 0$ for $j=1,\dots,n$ we can divide row $j$ ($1\leq j \leq n$) by the scalar $a_j-a_{n+1}$ by multiplying to the left by elementary matrices. Thus there is an invertible matrix $A_2$ such that
$$
A_2 V_{n+1}^T A_1^T = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & a_1 & a_1^2 & \cdots & a_1^{n-1}\\
1 & 1 & a_2 & a_2^2 & \cdots & a_2^{n-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
1 & 1 & a_n & a_n^2 & \cdots & a_n^{n-2}\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now we interchange rows to put row $n+1$ on top. Thus there is an invertible matrix $A_3$ such that
$$
A_3A_2V_{n+1}^T A_1^T = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
1 & 1 & a_1 & a_1^2 & \cdots & a_1^{n-1}\\
1 & 1 & a_2 & a_2^2 & \cdots & a_2^{n-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
1 & 1 & a_n & a_n^2 & \cdots & a_n^{n-2}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
We now substract row $1$ from row $j$ for $j=2,\dots,n+1$, so there is an invertible matrix $A_4$ such that
$$
A_4A_3A_2V_{n+1}^TA_1^T = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1 & a_1 & a_1^2 & \cdots & a_1^{n-1}\\
0 & 1 & a_2 & a_2^2 & \cdots & a_2^{n-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
0 & 1 & a_n & a_n^2 & \cdots & a_n^{n-2}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Taking transposes, we can write, in block notation
$$
A_1V_{n+1}B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \mathbf{0}_{1\times n}\\
\mathbf{0}_{n\times 1} & V_n
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $\mathbf{0}_{i\times j}$ is a $i\times j$ matrix of zeroes and $B=(A_4A_3A_2)^T$ is an invertible matrix. By induction hypothesis $V_n$ is invertible. Thus consider the block matrix
$$
C = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & \mathbf{0}_{1\times n}\\
\mathbf{0}_{n\times 1} & V_n^{-1},
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and a simple multiplication gives
$$
A_1V_{n+1}BC=CA_1V_{n+1}B = I_{n+1}
$$
where $I_{n+1}$ is the identity matrix of size $(n+1)\times(n+1)$. This shows that $V_{n+1}$ is invertible and that it equals $A_1^{-1}C^{-1}B^{-1}$.

**Note.** For the ones familiar with the computation of Vandermonde's determinant, it is clear that I just followed the computation of the determinant, so there is nothing new here but to make it a computation of the inverse. Also, taking transposes is to avoid the use of column operations, for the OP's comfort.

**ADDED**

As I said in the comments, here is a proof using linear maps. Let $F_n[x]$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree strictly less than $n$. We know that
$$
\dim_F F_n[x]=n.
$$
Consider the linear map
$$
T:F_n[x]\to F^{n}, \quad f(x)\mapsto (f(x_1),f(x_2),\dots,f(x_n)).
$$
This map is surjective. Indeed, let $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in F^n$. For each $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ let
$$
L_j(x) = \frac{(x-x_1)\cdots (x-x_{j-1})(x-x_{j+1})\cdots (x-x_n)}{(x_j-x_1)\cdots (x_j-x_{j-1})(x_j-x_{j+1})\cdots (x_j-x_n)}\in F_n[x].
$$
Note that $L_j(x_k)=\delta_{jk}$, where $\delta_{jk}$ is the Kronecker symbol. Now let
$$
f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j L_j(x)\in F_n[x],
$$
then $T(f)=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$. This shows that $T$ is surjective. Since both $F_n[x]$ and $F^n$ have dimension $n$, then $T$ is a vector space isomorphism, in particular the matrix of $T$ in any basis is invertible. Now let $B_1=(1,x,x^2,\dots,x^{n-1})$ which is a basis of $F_n[x]$ and let $B_2=(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ be the canonical basis of $F^n$. Then
$$
T(1)=e_1+e_2+\cdots+e_n
$$
and for $j\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$,
$$
T(x^j) = x_1^j e_1 + x_2^je_2+\cdots + x_n^j e_n.
$$
This means that the matrix of $T$ in this bases is
$$
[T] = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^{n-1}\\
1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & \cdots & x_2^{n-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_n^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and thus $[T]$ is invertible. But $[T]$ is the transpose of the Vandermonde matrix, so the latter is invertible.

Comment: That was perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @MasonRashford you're welcome. Actually, I wrote another proof using linear maps before this one. But I did not made it public since I don't know if it is elementary enough. However, I'm gonna add it anyway, since it can be helpful to other people.

Comment: Sorry, how did you find out $V_{n+1}$ is invertible by saying $A_1V_{n+1}BC=CA_1V_{n+1}B=I_{n+1}$ in the first proof?

Comment: From this relations you can conclude that $V_{n+1}=A_1^{-1}C^{-1}B^{-1}$, which means that $V_{n+1}$ is a product of invertible matrices and hence is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

The comments give good answers for short proofs of invertibility of the Vandermonde matrix. I'll give a not-so-short proof, but one which is as elementary as possible: using only row-reduction.

I'll show that the third Vandermonde matrix is invertible, which I think should be convincing that all of them are. Let $a,b,c$ be distinct elements of $F$. Then the following row-reductions take the Vandermonde matrix on $a,b,c$ to the identity:

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ a & b & c \\ a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \end{bmatrix} &\longrightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & b-a & c-a \\ 0 & b^2 - a^2 & c^2 - a^2 \end{bmatrix}\\
&\longrightarrow\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 - \frac{c-a}{b-a} \\ 0 & b-a & c-a \\ 0 & b^2 - a^2 & c^2 - a^2 \end{bmatrix}\\
&\longrightarrow\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 - \frac{c-a}{b-a} \\ 0 & b-a & c-a \\ 0 & 0 & c^2 - a^2 - (b+a)(c-a) \end{bmatrix}\\
&\longrightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 - \frac{c-a}{b-a} \\ 0 & b-a & c-a \\ 0 & 0 & (c-a)(c-b) \end{bmatrix}\\
&\longrightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 - \frac{c-a}{b-a} \\ 0 & b-a & c-a \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\longrightarrow I\\
\end{align*}
The first move is just annihilating everything below the first $1$, the second is using that $b-a \neq 0$ to divide and subtract from the first row, the third is using that $b^2-a^2 = (b-a)(b+a)$, the fourth is just algebra in the $(3,3)$th position that guarantees that we can divide by that element. The final matrix is evidently row-reducible to $I$, so we are done.

I hope this is convincing for the general case; to prove the general case (which might be a little hairy), observe that invertibility of the $n$th Vandermonde matrix amounts to invertibility of the (after reduction) first $n-1$ rows and columns, and that the bottom-right entry is nonzero. Using this, you can perform an induction.

Comment: I appreciate your guidance. But can you explain how $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 - \frac{c-a}{b-a} \\ 0 & b-a & c-a \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ goes to identity matrix $I$?

Comment: The last row has only a $1$ in the last entry, so we can just scale and subtract to annihilate everything above it. Since $b-a \neq 0$, we can divide the middle row by $b-a$, which gives us the identity.