# Show Vandermonde matrix is invertible using induction without knowing about determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

> Suppose $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ are different elements from the field
> $F$ (if $i\neq j$, then $a_i\neq a_j$). Show that this matrix is
> invertible: $$V=\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1&&\dots&&1\\
>  a_1&&a_2&&\dots&&a_n\\ a_1^2&&a_2^2&&\dots&&a_n^2\\
>  \vdots&&\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
>  a_1^{n-1}&&a_2^{n-1}&&\dots&&a_n^{n-1} \end{bmatrix}$$

I tried to prove it using induction. For base case of induction, $n=1$, it's trivial. Now suppose for some $n=k$, $V$ is invertible . We will show for $n=k+1$ is also correct. Denote $k\times k$ Vandermonde matrix as $V_k$. If $V_k$ is invertible, we can say with some elementary row operations, it can be converted to identity matrix ($V_k\sim I)$. Now, if we  do the same elementary row-operations we did on $V_k$, on $V_{k+1}$, the first $k\times k$ part of our $(k+1)\times(k+1)$ matrix, becomes the identity matrix $I_k$.  Using this part of $V_{k+1}$, we can also ommit $a_1^p,\dots,a_{p}^p$ and $1, a_{p+1},\dots,a_{p+1}^p$ entries (last row and last column except of the last entry) and convert $a_{p+1}^{p}$ to $1$. So it $V_{p+1}$ is row equivalent to identity matrix, hence, it's invertible. The induction is complete.

Are my approach and explanations correct?

Comment: There is something wrong in your argument: if any two $a_i$ are equal the matrix is **not** invertible. But you didn't take this into account anywhere.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut If any two $a_i$ are equal, two columns will be equal and and it can't be row equivalent to identity matrix. Yes?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez We make the first $p$ entries of the last row, zero. Then make the last entry one by dividing. Then make entries of the last column zero using the last entry.

Comment: @MasonRashford Certainly. But since you assume $V_k$ is invertible, the problem lies in the last column.

Comment: I don't see any easy way to save the proof. Since you want to do it by induction, why not just compute the determinant? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix#Third_proof:_row_and_column_operations

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks for your help, but I can't use determinant because this question is said during my linear algebra course and I'm not allowed to use determinant yet. I think this algorithm works. For example try to show $V_2$ is invertible using $V_1$ and then $V_3$ using $V_2$ and ... . I also will prove if two columns are identical, $V$ isn't invertible but besides this algorithm.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4790247/14578

Comment: I encourage you to review https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/35664/14578 and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20583/14578 and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35592/14578 before posting additional solution verification requests.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, the proof you have suggested doesn't quite work because you have to be careful about what happens in the last row/column. I am unsure how one would go about proving this via induction. If you are interested, here's a way to prove invertibility without determinants:

Assume for the sake of contradiction that the Vandermonde matrix is indeed not invertible. Then, there exists some linear dependence between its rows. This means there exist constants $c_0, c_1, \ldots, c_{n - 1} \in F$, not all equal to zero, such that:
$$c_{n-1}a_i^{n-1}+c_{n-2}a_i^{n-2}+\cdots+c_0 = 0$$
for all $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$. In other words, the polynomial $P(x) = c_{n-1}x^{n-1} + c_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\cdots+c_0$ has roots equal to $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$. However, $P(x)$ is a non-zero polynomial (since at least one $c_j$ is non-zero) and has degree less than $n$, so it cannot have $n$ distinct roots. Thus, we have the required contradiction.